# Initializer list for an unknown ("templated") amount of classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, initializer-list

If I have a class template which contains an array with another class as type with undefined amount of fields (the amount is a template parameter), how do I run their constructors (if they take parameters)?

Here some example code:

```
class ArrayClass
{
public:
    ArrayClass() = delete;
    ArrayClass(int anyParameter) {}
};

template <const int amountOfFields>
class ContainingClass
{
    ArrayClass myArray[amountOfFields];

public:
    ContainingClass();
};

template <const int amountOfFields>
ContainingClass<amountOfFields>::ContainingClass()
    :
    myArray(5)     // doesn't work of cause
{}
```

Is it possible to give every ArrayClass, no matter how many there are, the same parameter (or different ones)? (I don't essentially need it but it would make things easier for me)

Comment: i think std::vector is what you actually want

Comment: Well I think I could use a vector to get the same result (as if I had the possibility to use the initializer-list in the way I want to) but it's not exactly what I want.

the "ArrayClass" is in my original code a sprite and my ContainingClass a game object. As I might want to have animated sprites I made it a template so I could make it a GameObject with 5 sprites or 10 sprites or so on.

The problem with that is that my sprite class needs a pointer to one of my other classes and until now I used the constructor to pass it.

I was just wondering if there is a way of doing it with

Comment: the constructor, I know myself a few other ways of doing it

Comment: I mean if I'd use a vector I could make a for loop in the constructor which adds the correct amount of sprites to the vector so I don't need the initializer-list at all

But still - is it possible to do it with the initializer list?

Comment: You could give explicit values to all array elements, for example if you have `ContainingClass<4> cc;` then you could init it with `: myArray{2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: Okay thanks that is something I didn't know yet, but that would still require me to make a template specialization for every amount I want to be able to use wouldn't it?

Comment: You've missed the proper constructor for `vector`: `myArray(amountOfFields, ArrayClass(5))` creates a vector of specified length, all elements identical.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing in the C++ standard libraries for this case

If you’re compiling with GCC, it has a proprietary extension called ranged initialization. With GCC, you can write something like this (untested):

```
template<size_t amountOfFields>
ContainingClass<amountOfFields>::ContainingClass():
    myArray( { [0 ... (amountOfFields-1)] = 5} )
{ }
```

If you’re using any other compiler, you have following options.

1. As said by the commenters, replace array with std::vector, it has the constructor you need. However this will change RAM layout, i.e. if you have lots of containers with small number of elements each, arrays (both C arrays, and C++ std::array) will be faster because one less pointer to chase.
2. Remove “=delete” from the default constructor of your ArrayClass, use `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` in the ContainingClass constructor to set initial values after they’re already constructed. However this might bring some small runtime cost.
3. If you don’t have too many elements, technically you can use some template metaprogramming to implement statically-constructed arrays the way you want. However, IMO that’ll be substantial amount of very hard to debug C++ code (there’s no compile-time debugger).
4. If you have small number of different template arguments in your code, you can write a function like

   ```
   template<size_t N>
   constexpr std::array<ArrayClass,N> fill_array(int val)
   ```

specialize it for different values of amountOfFields temple arguments you have, and call the function in the constructor of ContainingClass.

Other solutions are possible, like external tools, macros, boost, etc… But I think 2 & 4 are the most reasonable workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me with GCC 8.1 / Clang 6.0 and C++14, though I am definitely not sure whether it is Standard compliant:

```
class E {
public:
   E() = delete;
   E(int i) : i_(i) { }
   operator int() const { return i_; }
private: 
   int i_;
};

template <typename T>
T dummy(T val, /* [[maybe_unused]] */ size_t I) { return val; }

template <typename T, size_t... I, typename U>
constexpr auto make_array_impl(U val, std::index_sequence<I...> is) {
   return std::array<T, is.size()>{dummy(val, I)...};
}

template <typename T, size_t N, typename U>
constexpr auto make_array(U val) {
   return make_array_impl<T>(val, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
class A {
public: 
   A(T val) : a_{make_array<T, N>(val)} { }
   void print() { for (auto e : a_) std::cout << e << std::endl; }
private:
   std::array<T, N> a_;
};

int main() {
   A<E, 5> a(-1);    
   a.print();
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Db9Zpf6gUMvg4MER

---

Updated more generic solution:

```
template <typename T, size_t... I, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_array_impl(std::index_sequence<I...> is, Args&&... args) {
   return std::array<T, is.size()>{ (I, T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))... };
}

template <typename T, size_t N, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_array(Args&&... args) {
   return make_array_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Haven’t thought about using `index_sequence` this way when I was writing my answer.

Comment: @Soonts Thanks, understanding `index_sequence` is a bit painful to understand but it has many nice applications. Note that I also update the answer to provide generic solution for any number of constructor arguments and there is no need for `dummy` function any more.