# Initialization of std::array<T,N> in constructor initializer list when T is not default-constructible

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50785002/580083), I wonder whether it's safe to construct `std::array<T,N>` in a constructor initializer list, if both `T` and `N` are template parameters and `T` is not default-constructible. I came up with the following helper functions:

```
template <typename T, size_t... I> 
constexpr auto make_array_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, const T& val) {
   return std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>{ (I, val)... };
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr auto make_array(const T& val) {
   return make_array_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, val);  
}
```

Now, if I have a class such as:

```
class E {
   public:
      E() = delete;
      E(int, int, int) { }
};
```

I can write:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class A {
   public:
      template <typename... Args>
      A(Args&&... args) : a_(make_array<T, N>(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) { }

   private:
      std::array<T, N> a_;
};
```

And then

```
A<E, 5> a(1, 2, 3);
```

This works for me with GCC 8.1 / Clang 6.0 and C++14 enabled. However, I am not sure whether such initialization of `a_` in the constructor initializer list is correct, and if so, whether this corectness depends on template parameter `T`.

*(To say the truth, I even can't find in the Standard whether `std::array` can be initialized by another `std::array`. Is it a part of aggregate-initialization? Or, does `std::array` support copy-initialization?)*

---

To clarify the question, what I want to achieve by

```
A<E, 5> a(1, 2, 3);
```

is that `a::a_` member function would effectively be initiated as

```
std::array<E, 5> a::a_ = { E(1,2,3), E(1,2,3), E(1,2,3), E(1,2,3), E(1,2,3) };
```

Comment: You don't want perfect forwarding when `N` != 1, or you'll move from the same source rvalues multiple times.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you delete the copy constructor (or the implicit one is deleted, which requires that some subobject has a deleted copy constructor or something of that nature), *every* type can undergo copy construction. So for a value `t` of any (non-array object) type `T`, if it is copy constructible, `T t2 = t;` will work.